# div on translating increases page width

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to translate multiple div one on top of each other such that each layer slides away.I used animate.css to for animation and used jquery to identify when the animation ends and to add a class to the container such that it hides hence it doesn't increase the page width. But regardless the page width is still increases.

I would also like to loop the animation.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8qzvhxmu/

HTML:

```
<div class="test animated "></div>
<div class="test1 animated  lightSpeedOut"></div>
```

CSS:

```
html,body
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.test
{
    background-color: #323232;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;

}

.test1
{
    background-color: #01c8c8;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;

}

.hide
{
    display: none;
}
```

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.test1').one('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend',function()
    {
        document.querySelector('.test1').classList.add("hide");
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you allow others to recreate your issue by posting some more realistic HTML? The issue could be related to a parent HTML element for instance.

Comment: Create a fiddle please?

Comment: @GerritBertier The div with the z-index 4 has to slide over the below div,such that leaving it visible. But on sliding it increase the page width

Comment: @YoramdeLangen http://jsfiddle.net/8qzvhxmu/

Comment: @RakeshRenzous Ok, I thought the HTML parent elements were more relevant here, hence the solution I proposed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a container/wrapper to the elements you'd like to animate and disable it's `overflow`, so it wont enlarge.

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/e62m6hfn/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="test animated"></div>
    <div class="test1 animated lightSpeedOut"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.test {
    background-color: #323232;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
    position: absolute;
}
.test1 {
    background-color: #01c8c8;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 4;
    position: absolute;
}
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

## Update

I created a Fiddle where the animation loops (independent of the number of items you want to animate).

The code might not be the cleanest, but it works.

**Fiddle with looping:** http://jsfiddle.net/e62m6hfn/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="test-animate  test"></div>
    <div class="test-animate  test1"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.container {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
.test-animate {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
}
.test {
    background-color: #323232;
}
.test1 {
    background-color: #01c8c8;
}
.bottom {
    z-index: -1;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
function animate($el) {
    $el.addClass('animated  lightSpeedOut');
}

var elCounter = 0;

$(document).ready(function () {
    elCounter = $('.test-animate').length;
    animate($('.test-animate').eq(elCounter - 1));

    $('.test-animate').on('webkitAnimationEnd mozAnimationEnd MSAnimationEnd oanimationend animationend', function () {
        elCounter = (elCounter > 1) ? elCounter-1 : $('.test-animate').length;
        $('.test-animate').removeClass('bottom');
        $(this).addClass('bottom');
        $(this).removeClass('animated  lightSpeedOut');
        animate($('.test-animate').eq(elCounter - 1));
    });
});
```

Comment: You could loop the animation using jQuery I suppose. I reckon you want to move out the `.test1` and reveal the `.test` again?

Comment: Hey, I'm gonna update my answer with the looping code, it's not the cleanest, but it shows you 1 way of doing this. You might want to clean it up a bit though.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `overflow: hidden;` to `html, body {}`.

```
html,body
{
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot.Is it possible for me to loop it like after the two are translated can i make the first to reappear and then do the same.